# SubGit and .gitattributes

Tags: gitattributes, subgit

I'm importing an SVN repository into Git, and I have a lot of files with `svn:eol-style` set. **SubGit** reads those properties and generates a `.gitattributes` line for *every* file.

Is there a way to tell it to use a single-liner for every type of file (i.e. `*.java text` or `*.java text eol=lf` since we have a style guide rule which mandates that)?

I tried to add the `info/attributes` to the repository just before the import, but there's no change in the generated `.gitattributes`.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there's no way to define default rules like `*.java test eol=lf` for initial translation, but if you later in a Git branch change `.gitattributes` to replace all per-file lines with one `*.java test eol=lf` rule, all subsequent Java files with svn:eol-style=LF won't result into new lines, but Java files with other svn:eol-style values will result into additional lines as exceptions to the `*.java test eol=lf` rule.

Moreover it is even recommended to have the `*.java test eol=lf` rule, because when you create a Java file in Git, `.gitattributes` rules are applied to it implicitly, so your newly created Java file will have "eol=lf" automatically and when you push it to Git, SubGit will translate it to svn:eol-style=LF. So this rule would act in the same way as SVN auto-properties.

SubGit doesn't consider `info/attributes` file at all, because it is not versioned and exists on local machine only while SubGit works on the server-side level. But you can use `info/attributes` on the local machine to override `.gitattributes` if you need that on one machine only.

I would also note that you should be careful when you change the `.gitattributes` file. When you push such a change to SVN, it will update svn:eol-style for all files for which the effective "eol" attribute value was changed.

One more note: be careful when you set the "eol" attribute for a file with mixed EOLs: change its EOLs to LF first at the Git blob level, or (what would be easier) set the `svn:eol-style` property on the SVN side instead, because when you set this property, Subversion automatically fixes file content, but Git doesn't do that.

You've mentioned two patterns, `*.java text` or `*.java text eol=lf`, but they are actually different. The first one is a particular case of a default `* text=auto !eol` rule, unless the Java file contains binary characters (as it doesn't contain the "eol" attribute, the main *-rule will set it to !eol, what corresponds to svn:eol-style=native); so it would be ignored when added. The second one will set svn:eol-style=LF for every Java file added to Git.

Finally, in the future versions, we (the SubGit team) plan to add a possibility to specify default `*.java test eol=lf` rules for initial translation or deduce it basing on per-extension statistics, but for now you should add this line manually to every Git branch you work with.

Comment: I've come up with a filter like this: `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp /some-absolute-path/gitattributes-template .gitattributes && cp /some-absolute-path/gitignore-template .gitignore' --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all` that should also clean up some dirt. Quite slow but should do the job.

Comment: This is only useful if you use SubGit for initial translation but not for continuous synchronization. Otherwise your Git commits will have different SHA-1 hash codes and internal revision <-> commit mappings in SubGit will become incorrect. If you don't like such .gitattributes and EOLs translation at all you can use `translate.eols` option of subgit/config file (default value: true); but you should set this option just after `subgit configure` step. When the option is set to false, SubGit ignores svn:eol-style and doesn't create .gitattributes file.