# How to skip generating .gitattribute file?

Tags: git, subgit

I am required to not to include .gitattribute. but subgit add it to the repository. could I know how can I stop subgit adding .gitattribute file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SubGit adds .gitattributes files in two cases: when [translate.eol](https://subgit.com/documentation/config-options.html#translate.eols)s is set to 'true' and when [translate.otherProperties](https://subgit.com/documentation/config-options.html#translate.otherProperties) is set to 'true'. The latter is 'false' by default, so I believe the .gitattribiutes file is being created because the 'eols' is 'true'. To prevent creating .gitattribiutes file the settings should be set to 'false' in SubGit configuration file:

```
[translate]
     eols = false
     otherProperties = false
```

The problem here is that the settings can't be changed on the fly, it must be set prior to the initial translation. So if the mirror has already been established, you would need to rebuild it to apply these settings:

```
subgit install --rebuild
```

After that the files should not appear any more.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

As [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) explains in "[Line endings handling in SVN, Git and SubGit](https://blog.subgit.com/line-endings-handling-in-svn-git-and-subgit/)", those `.gitattributes` files are needed, espacially if you are pushing back to SVN from the Git repo after conversion.
See for instance "[SubGit and `.gitattributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33013757/6309)".

But for a one-time conversion from SVN to Git, you could simply delete any `.gitattributes` files, add, and make a final commit recording those deletions:

```
 find . -name .gitattributes -delete
```